# Win cmd rar each file separately while keeping the name, with spaces

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, rar, winrar

I'm using Windows and I have a huge list of files

```
something nextthing.ext
other something.ext
banana apple.ext
```

I'm trying to generate the following:

```
something nextthing.rar
other something.rar
banana apple.rar
```

I've done some research and I couldn't find how to do this. I know WinRAR has a built in way to do this, but it won't let me keep the names. It just renames them to Foldername1.rar, Foldername2.rar ....

I tried using the following command line:

`for /f "delims=|" %f in ('dir /b "C:\Users\Adam\
Desktop\Files"') do rar a %f *.rar`

However, it doesn't generate all files and they seem to be named wrongly...

For example, what should be `banana apple.rar` becomes `banana.rar` and `apple.rar`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, found how....

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "path=C:\Program Files\WinRAR;%path%"

:indiv
echo(
echo(
FOR %%i IN (*) do (
    rar a "%%~ni.rar" "%%~i" || echo Error building archive!
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use in a command prompt window to compress each file in a directory into a separate archive:

```
for /f "delims=" %f in ('dir "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Files" /B /A-D') do "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -ep1 -idcdp "%~nf.rar" "%f"
```

Important are the double quotes around `%f` as some file names contain 1 or more spaces and in this case the file names must be enclosed in double quotes.

Above command for usage in a batch file:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Files" /B /A-D') do "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -ep1 -idcdp "%%~nf.rar" "%%f"
```

This command ignores subfolders because of `/A-D`. It compresses only each file in directory `Files` on desktop of current user.